# Install Shadow demon on ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: server, vmware

Hi for best security practise , I would like to install Shadow deamon  (web application firewall) in virtual environement using vmware workstation 16.x..
I install docker  , download the file  from git -> git clone https://github.com/zecure/shadowd.git

keep follow instruction from official website ->https://shadowd.zecure.org/overview/shadowd_source/
Each time I got this error that cannot fix may you help or guide me ....

> Blockquote

directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory contai
Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (message):
libdbi is missing

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMs:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
used as include directory in directory /home/jose/build
used as include directory in directory /home/jose/build

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jose/build/shadowd/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jose/build/shadowd/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

> Blockquote